# "wp_editor" not displaying TinyMCE correctly when square brackets used in name

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I'm creating a custom options page and I have a textarea that I've turned into a TinyMCE editor using wp_editor.

TinyMCE displays correctly, however it breaks when I include square brackets in the $id. Here's the code I'm using for the add_settings_field function callback:

```
function px_wp_editor($args){
        $options    = get_option('theme_options');  
        $value      = $options['px_wp_editor'];
        $id         = 'theme_options[px_wp_editor]';

         extract( $args );
         $class = (!empty($class))?$class:'';

         $settings = array(
            'textarea_rows'     => 12,
            'textarea_name'     => $id, 
            'editor_class'      => $class,
            'media_buttons'     => true,
            'tinymce'           => true
         );
         wp_editor($value, $id, $settings );            
    }
```

If I removed the square brackets from the $id value then it displays fine. However, because of the way I'm retrieving the values using get_option, I need to call "textarea_name" as it currently is, with square brackets.

The first pic below is how it looks when using square brackets for the name (full icons don't display correctly and there are no Visual/Text buttons.

The second pic is how it should display.

[image: Here's a screenshot of how it looks when using square brackets for the name]
[image: Here's how it should look]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put square brackets as editor id. but you can change textarea name by.

```
wp_editor('','px_wp_editor',array('textarea_name' => 'theme_options[px_wp_editor]'));
```

the important part is, "id" and "textarea_name" are different.

Comment: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.

Comment: the important part is "id" and "textarea_name" are different. thats all. thats all.

Comment: Then please, tell that in your answer, and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this right now, but try this:

```
$id = htmlentities('theme_options[px_wp_editor]');
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Comment: Sad Christmas. :( I'll try to test this myself and work out why this doesn't work when I get a moment.